# C function fwrite() doesn't write in file

Tags: c, file-io, io, fwrite

I'm trying to write structures from `tempGroupFile` into `GroupFile`. `fwrite()` returns 1, when writing, but actually no data is written in the file `GroupFile`. Function `printRec()` prints out the structure on the screen. `data` is a variable of structure. File `GroupFile` is empty after these operations.
Code:

```
GWTemp = fopen(tempGroupFile, "rb");
GW = fopen(GroupFile, "wb"); 
if((GW == NULL) || (GWTemp == NULL))
{
    puts("Failed to open file.");
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
while(fread(&data, sizeof data, 1, GWTemp))
{
    if(fwrite(&data, sizeof data, 1, GW))
    {
        printRec(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you call `fclose` on `GroupFile`?

Comment: Is `sizeof(data) == 1`, because if `fwrite` is returning `1`, then that's all that is being written each time.

Comment: Yes, I called fclose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to close the file using fclose(GW) after the while loop.  This makes sure all buffers are flushed so the file is written.