# C - write to file faild when I put function fwrite() in a loop

Tags: c, linux, sockets, fwrite

I want to receive a file through a TCP socket on Linux. But I just get a empty file. However when I delete line 1 (while), anything will go okay. My code on server looks like this:

```
while(1) 
{ 



  FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "w"); 
  if(NULL == fp) 
  { 
    printf("File:\t%s Can Not Open To Write\n", file_name); 
    exit(1); 
  } 

  bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE); 
  int length = 0; 
  while((length = recv(new_server_socket_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) > 0) 
  { 

    if(fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), length, fp) < length) 
    { 
      printf("File:\t%s Write Failed\n", file_name); 
      break; 
    } 
    bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE); 
}
```

One thing I can make sure is that "if(fwrite(...))" do execude cause I put a putchar('a') out of if()  and I can get some "a" on my screen. All data will be transfered through socket new_server_socket_fd

Comment: `fwrite()` assumes the file is open in binary mode.   You have opened it in text mode (the default).   One possible consequence of opening in text mode is what you are seeing.  Also, within the outer loop, it is necessary to close the file

Comment: @Peter.  As I recall text mode is a dos thing.  In Unix text is simply whether or not it has carriage control characters.   What am I overlooking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C function fwrite() doesn't write in file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172591/c-function-fwrite-doesnt-write-in-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fclose** the file before you return.